# Is there any way to run playwright test cases in headed mode on jenkins?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, playwright

I want to run some test case on headed mode on jenkins as they were failing on headless mode, If anyone has done some sort of implementation then please let me know in thread.

I have heard about xvfb plugin but did not try it out.

Comment: How are you running playwright tests in headless mode currently on Jenkins?

Comment: And as they are failing you mentioned, what are the errors?